# Sorting an object based php array

Tags: php

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to sort this array by username from a mssql query. have tried using a couple of sort functions that others have made on the web, but have had no luck Any help would be amazing!

```
function getSalesPersonTargetTracker()
{
$targetTracker = new StdClass();
$targetTracker->agents = array();

$server = 'blah';
$connectioninfo = array( 'database' => 'blah', 'uid' => 'blah', 'pwd' => 'blah' );

$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectioninfo);

$query = "{call salespersontargettracker (?)}";
$params = array(
                 date_format(new DateTime(), '01/M/Y')
            );

//Run the Query             
$statement = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, $params);

if (sqlsrv_fetch($statement) === false)
     print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true);

//Read in the overall numbers
$targetTracker->target = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 0);
$targetTracker->workingDays = (int)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 1);
$targetTracker->currentDay = (int)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 2);
$targetTracker->dailyTarget = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 3);
$targetTracker->pointsShouldBeOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 4);
$targetTracker->pointsOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 5);
$targetTracker->pointsDifference = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 6);
$targetTracker->moneyShouldBeOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 7);
$targetTracker->moneyOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 8);
$targetTracker->moneyDifference = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 9);

//Move to the next result
sqlsrv_next_result($statement);

//Run through all of the agents and show their details
while (sqlsrv_fetch($statement))
{
    $salesPerson = new StdClass();
    $salesPerson->team = sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 0);
    $salesPerson->username = sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 1);
    $salesPerson->target = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 2);
    $salesPerson->workingDays = (int)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 3);
    $salesPerson->currentDay = (int)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 4);
    $salesPerson->dailyTarget = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 5);
    $salesPerson->pointsShouldBeOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 6);
    $salesPerson->pointsOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 7);
    $salesPerson->pointsDifference = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 8);
    $salesPerson->moneyShouldBeOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 9);
    $salesPerson->moneyOn = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 10);
    $salesPerson->moneyDifference = (float)sqlsrv_get_field($statement, 11);

    //Add this person to the people list
    $targetTracker->agents[] = $salesPerson;
}

return $targetTracker;
}
$targetTrackerall = getSalesPersonTargetTracker();

?>
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><center>Username</center></th>
                <th><center>Day</center></th>   
                <th><center>%</center></th>     
                <th><center>% +/-</center></th>                 
                <th><center>Actual Total</center></th>
                <th><center>+/- Total</center></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <?php 
    //This loops through every single agent in our array
    foreach ($targetTrackerall->agents as $agent) {
        //If their points difference is a negative, then name & shame them
        if ($agent->pointsDifference < 0)
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><b><?php echo $agent->username ?></b></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $agent->currentDay  ?> / <b><?php echo $agent->workingDays?></b></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $agent->pointsOn ?>%</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo round($agent->pointsDifference) ?>%</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">£<?php echo number_format($agent->moneyOn) ?></td>
                <td style="color: red; text-align: center;">-£<?php echo number_format(($agent->moneyDifference)*-1) ?></td>

    <?php

        }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: At an `ORDER BY` clause to your database query...!

Comment: What do you get? What do you want? What code is relevant for your problem?

Comment: Can't add an order by to the database query as is used for other things! Would be the easiest way :->

Comment: Take a look at OPENQUERY.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx  something like SELECT  *  INTO #tmp FROM OPENQUERY(yourserverr, 'EXEC salespersontargettracker (?)') ORDER BY ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the username field is unique then you can use it as the key for the agents array and use ksort on the array.

```
<?php
...

while (sqlsrv_fetch($statement))
{
  ...

  //Add this person to the people list
  $targetTracker->agents[$salesPerson->username] = $salesPerson;
  ksort($targetTracker->agents);
}
...

?>
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you. Just need to find out how to make it ignore capitalisation!

Comment: @AdamClark you can use `$targetTracker->agents[strtolower($salesPerson->username)] = $salesPerson;`. If your php version is above 5.4.0, you can also use `ksort($targetTracker->agents, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and write a callback function like

```
    }
    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a->username, $b->username);
    }
    usort($targetTracker, 'cmp');

    return $targetTracker;
}
```

Comment: how would I integrate this function into the code above, I'm pretty useless!

Comment: You could put it in your function before returning the array, declare the sorting function then call the usort one

Comment: tried this but am having no luck  return $targetTracker;
}
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->username, $b->username);
}

$targetTrackerall = getSalesPersonTargetTracker();
$targetTrackerallt = cmp($targetTrackerall)